# How do I redirect a user to some other views.py if nothing is found in the query set?

Tags: python, django

I'm trying this code in django:

The **urls.py** has:

```
re_path(r'^(?P<site_url_var>[-\w.]+)/$', views.FnDetails, name='detail'),
```

The **views.py** has:

```
def FnDetails(request, site_url_var):
    try:
        url_details = detail.objects.get(page_end_url=site_url_var)
    except detail.DoesNotExist:
        raise Http404("Url Does Not Exist")

    return render(request, 'base.html', {'url_details' : url_details})
```

But in some cases when the values are present in some other `url.py`, it returns an HTTP 404 error.

What I want is something which does something like:

```
except:
    redirect("to Other View")
```

Comment: You should **`return`** the `redirect(..)`. `redirect(..)` is only a HTTP response object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [redirect helper](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/http/shortcuts/#redirect). Pay particular attention to the second example:

```
from django.shortcuts import redirect

def my_view(request):
    try:
        ...
    except:
        return redirect('url-name-from-urls', foo='bar')
```

The url name `'url-name-from-urls'` should match the `name=` keyword argument that you've given to a url in `urls.py`. For example:

```
from django.shortcuts import redirect

def my_view(request):
    try:
        ...
    except:
        return redirect('detail')
```

Would redirect to your `FnDetails` view, because it matches the `name='detail'` url.

Comment: checking the same, will revert accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like

```
try:
    # Your regular logic here
except Exception as e: 
    return HttpResponseRedirect('/yourpath/')
```

This assumes

```
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
```

also, that path `yourpath` needs to be added to `urls.py`

Comment: checking the same, will revert accordingly.